# HTML to Image file using Painty

Tags: php, javascript, html, image-manipulation

I am using Painty. http://www.rabuser.info/painty.php So far so good.  But my question is now how would I make it create the image file instead of outputting it to the screen.  In fact I want it to create it without the user even going to the page maybe through AJAX.

In the end this is how it will flow.  They will go to there profile.  From there it run some ajax and create an image from some HTML i specified and display the image on there profile.  They would also be able to link to this image and show it off hence the reason I want it to be a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After imagepng($im); you can add this line:

```
imagejpeg($im, 'yoo.jpg', 75); //creates jpeg file at 75 percent quality
```

if it still doesn;t work, then:

After $html=@$_GET['html']; add this line:

```
 $html='<h1>Painty Heading</h1><hr/><p>Welcome<br /><b>Yo...</b></p><p align = right><img src="http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif" align="right" /></p>';
```

and after 'font_path' => $__SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"],
add this line:

```
'font_path' => "./",
```

and i also recommend these fonts:

```
'font' => "VeraMono.ttf",
'font_bold' => "VeraMoBd.ttf",
```

find those files in C:\Windows\fonts

Answer (score 1):

Well, Painty **should be** producing an image. Make sure you have set up your headers correctly, as per painty.php's instructions:

```
$config = array(
    'input' => $_GET['html'],
    'output' => "png",
    'width' => 400,
    'height' => 300,
    'font_path' => "./",
    'font' => "tahoma.ttf",
    'font_bold' => "tahoma.ttf",
    '' => ''
);
$str = $config['input'];
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{
    $str = stripslashes($str);
}
$im = painty($str);
//Set header. secured from header injection.
```

**Most important part:**

```
header("Content-Type: image/".str_replace("\r\n", "", $config['output']));
imagepng($im);
```

The `header` command tells the server to treat the file as an image– even though it may be named `image-generator.php`. If you treat the file as an image as well, it should be fine:

```
<a href="image-generator.php?username=foo&level=36&class=Demoman">
    <img src="image-generator.php?username=foo&level=36&class=Demoman" />
</a>
```

This is assuming `image-generator.php` has been set up to accept $_POST data. Then `image-generator.php` creates an HTML file from that data and sends it to Painty as input.

Good luck!